# scrolling with openGl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on openGl in android and stuck with some issue. I have a image set on my screen now on double tap i want to zoom it and then apply scrolling. How do i do it without using a lot of memory. PLease suggest

Comment: Is it safe to assume the camera is Orthographic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood the problem..but I have used simply gltranslate for scrolling. On each MOVE_EVENT I add the distance to local variable and use it in glTranslate

Answer (score 1):

for zoom I have used scalef factor and to make it zoom in specific area use
gl.glScissor(0,0,120,120). for details regarding glScissor visit http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glScissor.html

Then change your translate factor according to scroll amount.

It worked for me. Hope it helps someone else too.